# Show records from one table to another

Tags: ms-access-2010, criteria

I am trying to create criteria on a query so when I select the current Period into a combobox on a form the Dates will filter to only show dates between START and END (Located on a Table). For example, If I where to write

```
IF[PComboBox].[Text] = ([Period]) ([Period]) BETWEEN ([Start]) and ([End])
```

I have a table that contains 3 Fields, (Period) which is 26 records starting from 1. I have (Start) (End) which detail what date each period is between.

I then have another table which has all the client records and the start date for each job called. (Matter_OpenDate).

The criteria above is under Matter_OpenDate on the query.

The code is definitely very wrong but hopefully someone can understand it and help me out.

Hopefully this is understandable to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be:

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    TablePeriod, 
    TableMatter
Where
    TablePeriod.Period = [Forms]![YourFormName]![PCombobox]
    And
    TableMatter.Matter_OpenDate Between TablePeriod.Start And TablePeriod.End
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing this right, where would I put this code, Criteria won't accept it.

Comment: That's the full SQL. Switch to SQL view of a new query and modify to fit your actual table and field names.